# Glob pattern: Exclude file only from top directory

Tags: python, unix, glob

Lets take a below example as my folder structure,

```
|---GCD.txt
|---Azure.png
|---AWS.txt
|---foo/
|     |--- app.txt
|     |--- bar.txt
```

**GCD.txt, azure.png, AWS.txt** files are at root folder. I don't know the folder name(New GUID every time).

Now I want to write a glob pattern such that text file(*.txt) only from root folder should skip, not from sub-folders. So expected behavior should be,

```
|---Azure.png
|---foo/
|     |--- app.txt
|     |--- bar.txt
```

**GCD.txt** and **AWS.txt** should be skipped.

My attempts:

```
.*.txt
./*.txt
*.txt
```

None of the above pattern helped. Am I missing something.

Comment: You will probably have to use os.walk() and check where you are in the directory hierarchy in order to eliminate unwanted files

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an expression that can be passed to glob that will do this. Here's how it could be done though:

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join
from pathlib import Path

files_of_interest = []
base_directory = '.'

def istxt(filename):
    return Path(filename).suffix.lower() in {'.txt'}

for root, _, files in walk(base_directory):
    if root == base_directory:
        for file in files:
            if not istxt(file):
                files_of_interest.append(join(root, file))
    else:
        for file in files:
            if istxt(file):
                files_of_interest.append(join(root, file))

print(files_of_interest)
```